# Best practice for wrapping `AVPlayerView` in `SwiftUI`?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to wrap `AVPlayerView` into `SwiftUI`. Here are my codes(playground):

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

class RecorderPlayerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var playerView: AVPlayerView

    init() {
        self.playerView = AVPlayerView()
        self.playerView.player = AVPlayer()
    }

    func reload(url: URL) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        self.playerView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    }
}

struct RecorderPlayerView: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = AVPlayerView

    var playerView: AVPlayerView

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AVPlayerView {
        return playerView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: AVPlayerView, context: Context) {}

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var playerViewModel: RecorderPlayerModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        RecorderPlayerView(playerView: playerViewModel.playerView)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            .onAppear {
               let fileManager = FileManager.default
                if let url = URL(string: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4") {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

                            let fileUrl = fileManager.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sample")
                                .appendingPathExtension(for: .mpeg4Movie)

                            try? fileManager.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
                            fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileUrl.path, contents: data)

                            playerViewModel.reload(url: fileUrl)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Button {
                if playerViewModel.playerView.canBeginTrimming {
                    Task {
                        await playerViewModel.playerView.beginTrimming()
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("trim")
            }
        }.frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .center)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Since I want to trim the video, I cannot directly use [`VideoPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer). But after wrapping `AVPlayerView` to `NSViewRepresentable` View, the trim view always lose interactivity.

Reproduce way: just double click at anywhere **when trimming**.

[image: reproduction]

---

#### supplement

when losing interactivity, the console will log

```
-[AVTrimIndicatorAccessibilityElement accessibilityHitTest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001916ce0
```

#### updated

It is not triggered on all models of Mac.

Comment: Works fine here - only replaced bundled mp4 with online mp4. Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4

Comment: Try before editing to copy file into tmp folder, inside bundle it is read-only, you know.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks. This is the code snippet. Actually in my project, the player will read the file from `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.appendingPathComponent("...")` exported by `AVAssetExportSession`. Double click at 'trimming boundary' still lead to lose interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the problem. It seems that applying `.clipShape(...)` on `RecorderPlayerView` will cause the problem.

Just remove the line `.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))` will solve this problem.

```swift
RecorderPlayerView(playerView: playerViewModel.playerView)
     // .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)) <-- remove this line
    .onAppear {
       ...
    }
```